# How do I stop Git from overwriting my db connection file?

Tags: database, git, gitignore

I have a file "db-connection.php" that has to be different for each version of my server. (Localhost, Dev and Production). At first I thought `.gitignore` was the answer, but after much pain and research, I realized that `.gitignore` only works on untracked file: e.g. files NOT already in the Repo.

For obvious reasons, the localhost version I'm using with *xampp* requires that the db file be within the repo. Of course, this means that every time I push it to Dev, it ruins the Dev db connection.

Is there a way to tell .git "Yes, I realize this file exists, but leave it alone anyway"?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem, and there are two solutions, depending on your needs.

First, if you always are going to have the same configuration files and they will change depending only on the environment (but not the developer machine), then simply create the three versions of the file in your repository (e.g., in a `config` directory), and copy the appropriate one into place, either with a script or manually.  You then remove the `db-connection.php` file and ignore it.

If this file actually needs to depend on the user's system (say, it contains personal developer credentials or system-specific paths), then you should ship a template file and copy it into place with a script (which may fill out the relevant details for the user).  In this case, too, the `db-connection.php` would be ignored and removed from the repository.

There are two things people try to do that don't work.  One of them is to try to keep multiple branches each with their own copy of the file.  This doesn't work because Git doesn't really provide a way to not merge certain files between branches.

The other thing people try to do is just ignored the changes to a tracked file using some invocation of `git update-index`.  That breaks in various cases because doing that isn't supported, and the [Git FAQ entry](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIignorechangestoatrackedfile) and the [`git update-index` manual page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_notes) explain why.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `skip worktree` option with `git-update-index` when you don't want git to manage the changes to that file.

```
git update-index --skip-worktree db-connection.php
```

Reference: [Skip worktree bit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_skip_worktree_bit)

Comment: You missed [the notes section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_notes) at the bottom of that page where it specifically says not to use it for that purpose.